# Wrong image thumbnail on Facebook for (blogger aka blogspot)

Tags: html, css, facebook, image, facebook-graph-api

I have a blogger (ameliaily.blogspot.com) and I am trying to get images from the blog to post as a thumbnail on Facebook and I have tried many things and none work. I still keep getting the og:image is not big enough error.

I have searched many forums and looked at all the answers I could find and it is still not working. I do not want FB to keep using my googleusercontent image as the picture (it is my personal photo and I don't want it to be the thumbnail used).

Below are the things I have tried:

1. Changing the size of the actual image. I've tried making it exactly 200 x 200 px, I've tried making it a rounded number i.e. 600 x 400 instead of 541 x 441.
2. Uploading the actual image to blogger.
3. Uploading the actual image to photobucket and THEN linking that image to blogger.
4. Adding the open graph code to my template HTML as suggested by these two forums: blogger-hints-and-tips.blogspot.com/2013/06/add-facebook-open-graph-tags-to-blogger-for-better-looking-shares-and-likes.html and www.bloggerhow.com/2012/07/implement-open-graph-in-blogger-blogs.html

   5) These are the images that I am trying to use as thumbnails: http://smg.photobucket.com/user/dizzyuptheblue/media/Blogger/balancebeam-4.jpg.html and http://smg.photobucket.com/user/dizzyuptheblue/media/Blogger/image004.jpg.html

They are both huge images so I don't know why FB keeps telling me it is not large enough.

Comment: Can you include the `og:image` tag which you have tried in your question?

Answer (score 0):

I had a look at the source of your page, and it looks like you are using a tag like this for the image:

```
<meta content='http://smg.photobucket.com/user/dizzyuptheblue/media/Blogger/image004.jpg.html' property='og:image'/>
```

The file type of the URL in this tag needs to be an image - at the moment, it is an HTML file which shows an image. You need the direct URL to the image. To get this, you can visit that page (ending in image0004.jpg.html) and right click on the image, copy the image URL and use this copied value in the tag instead - so the tag should become this:

```
<meta content='http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v235/dizzyuptheblue/Blogger/image004.jpg' property='og:image'/>
```

Try that instead and then test it out on the [Facebook Open Graph debugger.](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://ameliaily.blogspot.co.uk/)